# Export to Excel - Cannot connect to the server at this time. Changes to your data cannot be saved

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am facing the above mentioned issue with Export to Excel feature in SharePoint 2013. When I click on Export to Excel, I am able save the owssvr.iqy file however when I am trying to open that file using Excel I am receiving the above issue.

I did search on this issue and found multiple suggestions and tried everything and nothing worked. Below is the list of things that I have already verified.

1. This is definitely not an issue with Office Excel versions because other web applications are working fine.
2. I have added the site to trusted sites, compatibility view mode in IE.
3. I have compared the web.config files of working and non-working web applications and I did not find any difference except Machine key
4. I have compared the web application properties using SharePoint 2013 Manager of working and non-working web applications and I did not find any difference

My Environment Details:

1. I have a default 80 web application and there is no issue. I have another web application with two URLs (host headers). One for intranet users and another for Extranet users and issue exists with both URLs in this web application.

Also, note that this is the web application migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013

Any suggestions will be greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: can you check SharePoint web services app pool, is it started?